# Spring Boot + MongoRepository, get all rows but only certain fields

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to fetch all the entries in my database, but only the `reference` fields. In my `MongoRepository`, I want to use a custom query, so it doesn't use the method name to build up the query. The following doesn't seem to work:

```
public interface JvRepository extends MongoRepository<Jv, String> {
    @Query(value = "{}", fields = "{ id : 0, reference : 1 }")
    public List<String> findAllJvReferences();
}

public class Jv {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String reference;
}
```

The error is:

> Jv cannot be cast to `java.lang.String`

I tell it to not get the `id`, and do get the `reference` right? Why does it not return a `String`, but still a `Jv`?

I guess I should pass something in the value that tells Mongo to select everything, but I have no idea what. Or is there something else wrong with this code?

Comment: Use `List<Jv>` instead of `List<String>`. Don't worry the `id` field won't get populated

Comment: That works yes, the other fields are all NULL. But is there no way to let it really return a list of Strings, as this method is used by a REST API that should only return the references in a list. 
I guess I could iterate over the List<Jv> and extract the references, but I was hoping not having to do that.

Comment: I guess you could provide a custom implementation but returning the `List<Jv>` is the easier approach. You can simply convert it to a `List<String>` using Java 8's *Stream API*, `jvs.stream().map(Jv::getReference).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Hmm yeah, guess I'll stick to that. Thanks a lot!